# Guest checkout,redirected to login everytime

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to leverage the features of the out of the box guest checkout features of Hybris for my new storefront.
However,whenever I try to add address or payment method,I am redirected back to the login page,where I clicked on "Continue as guest".Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There is a filter called AnonymousCheckoutFilter, which checks if the user leaves the checkout during guest checkout. If the user visits a page outside of the checkout, hybris will redirect a pending guest checkout of the user to cart/login. Look for logs of RequireHardLoginEvaluator especially for this log output:

```
LOG.warn((guid == null ? "missing secure token in session" : "no matching guid cookie") + ", login required");
```

If you added a step to your checkout, its url needs to match the checkout pattern configured in the following property:

```
mystorefront.checkout.url.pattern
```

Default is:

```
mystorefront.checkout.url.pattern=(^https://.*/checkout/.*)
```

Comment: @,thanks a lot for your answer.Here I was getting the same warning that you mentioned.I am somehow trying to prevent this redirection by checking the url for each of the actions.Is it the correct approach?

Comment: In your checkout there should only be urls that contain "/checkout/". That would be my approach.

Comment: ,thanks a lot for your help.I checked this key but was not able to find this in the Platform->Configuration in the Administration console.So I dynamically added this key but found that the redirection still continues

Comment: What is the URL after which the redirect occurs? What is the name of your storefront?

Comment: @,the URL formed is /trainingstorefront/DE_B2C_Store/login/checkout and name of my storefront is trainingstorefront

Comment: Then look for a property called trainingstorefront.checkout.url.pattern. Also have a look at your access log. It shows exactly what requests your server processes. Find it in /hybris/log/tomcat/access.YYYY-mm-dd.log.

Comment: @,thanks the redirection was due to an open AJAX call so removing that helped.However when I land on the new page,when I try to add a new address,I am not able to add a new address as the validation of the GuestForm fails with the message "the country iso cannot be null" but there was no country field in the form.Whwre am I going wrong?